# Cannot deploy SSIS via Integration Services to SQL Server 2012: Current transaction canot be committed. Error:3930

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

I have a SSIS that has been working for over a year, and just in a couple of days I made a bunch of changes. When I try to deploy, it returns me an error saying

> The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.

It doesn't tell me what or which package is causing this issue.

Is there any way to trouble shoot this?

I appreciate any recommendation!!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the reason of the error was trigger on SSISDB DB for DDL_DATABASE_LEVEL_EVENTS, wich tried to write info in another DB.

Comment: I experienced this issue trying to deploy multiple SSIS packages automatically with using command line and PowerShell. The solution was to pause after each deployment: Start-Sleep -Seconds 2

Answer (score 0):

I just solve it, the partitionw as running out of free space, I just cleaned the log, and it's back to normal!

Answer (score 0):

I changed the name of my Solution and Project but wanted to deploy to the same location in the SSISDB Catalog. I was getting this specific error because of the name change (it was failing on deployment step when it called the internal.preparedeploy procedure). I ended up deleting the Project that existed on the Target Server and re-deploying the new Project to the same location. It deployed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Just deploy the whole project rather than SSIS Package.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).